# How to change "Camera and Photo Library Permission" description?

Tags: ios

I have specified the text I needed in the info.plist file in the NSCameraUsageDescription and NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription fields, but nothing has changed.

Always the same system text "this app requires access to the camera" and "this app requires access to the photo library". I have already tried to find it in code. Did not find. I specified in the files info.plist add my NSCameraUsageDescription and NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription keys , in the all libraries what I use. All the same nothing changes.

**info.plist file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Mona</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>The program wants to access the camera so you can use your photos and camera in this photo editor.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>The program wants to access the photo gallery so you can use your photos and camera in this photo editor.</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Alert image**
[image: Alert image]

Please help me. Tell me how to change the description of these queries.

Comment: Please post the info.plist of your app target.

Comment: @shallowThought done

Comment: You can't replace the system text, only add to it. Show screenshots of your permission alerts.

Comment: @Gereon done look

Comment: This is definitely not the system text. The string "this app requires access to the camera" _has_ to be somewhere in your project, maybe a localization/strings file.

Comment: @Gereon I searched in the whole project. Through search and manual, there is no (

Comment: Are you using a third party library?

Comment: @shallowThought yep Gallery 2.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string exists in the example project of the `Gallery` lib you are using.

```
   grep -r requires .
```

returns:

```
./Gallery-2.2.0/Example/GalleryDemo/GalleryDemo/Info.plist:     <string>This app requires access to camera</string>
./Gallery-2.2.0/Example/GalleryDemo/GalleryDemo/Info.plist:     <string>This app requires access to photo library</string>
```

That might have several reasons:

1. wrong plist

You do *not* use the .plist you posted but the one above

2. Xcode caching

You are using the same bundle id as you already used for running the Gallery sample code. To make sure no cache is used:

- close Xcode
- Delete the app from device / simulator
- clean derived data
- open Xcode, build & run

Comment: @Ivan Koval: what was it? 1 or 2?

Comment: It turned out that the info.plist that was on the left between the files was completely different than the info.plist in the Info tab in the TARGETS properties.